# Existence of an integral in T

Tags: real-analysis

I have $T=\{(x,y,z)\in R^3: z\ge 0,\; z\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1 \}$ and I want compute if it exists :

$$\int_T \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1)\quad e^{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\quad e^{-z^2} }{x^2+y^2}\,dx\, dy\, dz$$

I use the change in polar coordinates: $x=r \cos \theta, \; y=r \sin \theta,\ z=z$

so I define $D=\{(r,\theta,z)\in R^3: 0\le r\le \frac{1}{z} ,\;z \in [0,+\infty),\;\theta \in [0,2\pi) \}$, and I compute

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty }dz \int_{0}^{2\pi}d\theta\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{z}} \frac{(r+1)e^\frac{-1}{r} -r e^{-z^2}}{r} dr$$

But how can I prove the integral is finite?

Computing the integral I obtained:

$2\pi \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-z}-e^{-z^2}}{z}$ dz

I call g(z) the integrand function. The integral has problems in zero and $+\infty$.

1) in zero: $g(z)\sim -1$ for $z \rightarrow +\infty$ so g is integrables near zero

But for $+\infty$?

Comment: The main problem is for the lower limit of $r$.  $e^{-\frac{1}{r}}\to 0$ in the numerator a lot faster than $r$ in the denominator as $r\to 0$.  For the remaining term $r$ in the numerator cancels $r$ in the denominator.  Net result, the integrand is not singular at $r=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two potential problems; the $\frac1r$ factor as $r\to 0$, and the integral over $z$. To do this, we'll split the terms of the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac1z}\left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}-e^{-z^2}\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$
First, the $e^{-z^2}$ term. That breezes through the first two steps of integrating $dr$ and $d\theta$, leading to
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{z}e^{-z^2}\,dz$$
That integral diverges to $\infty$. The $z\to\infty$ behavior is fine, but small values of $z$ break it - they allow too much room for $r$ to grow, without the function decaying.

Next, the $r$ term. For that one, we switch the order:
\begin{align*}\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac1z} \left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}\,dr\,d\theta\,dz &= \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac1r}\left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}\,dz\,d\theta\,dr\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{r}\left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}\,dr\end{align*}
That integral diverges to $\infty$ as well. As $r\to\infty$, $e^{-1/r}\to 1$, and the integrand is comparable to $\frac1r$. The values of our original function don't decay as $r\to\infty$, and there's just too much room for small $z$.

So then, we have a $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate form, and both halves cause trouble by being relatively large in the same small-$z$, big-$r$ region. We're going to have to look closer at the possibility of cancellation.

If we restrict the region to $r\le M$, the two terms give us integrals $\int_0^{1/M}2\pi Me^{-z^2}\,dz+\int_{1/M}^{\infty}\frac{2\pi}{z}e^{-z^2}\,dz$ and $\int_0^M \frac{2\pi}{r}\left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}\,dr$, both of which converge (the latter because rapid decay of $e^{-1/r}$ means there's no singularity at zero). The difference thus converges absolutely on this part of the region.

That leaves us with the complementary part in which $r>M$. Here, we estimate $e^{-1/r}=1+O(r^{-1})$, so $\left(1+\frac1r\right)e^{-1/r}=1+O(r^{-1})$. Also, $e^{-z^2}=1+O(z^2)$. Combine these, and our integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\frac1M}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_M^{\frac1z}\left(1+O(r^{-1})\right)-\left(1+O(z^2)\right)\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$
$$\int_0^{\frac1M}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_M^{\frac1z}O(r^{-1})+O(z^2)\,dr\,d\theta\,dz$$
$$\int_0^{\frac1M}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_M^{\frac1z}O(z^2)\,dr\,d\theta\,dz+\int_M^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac1r}O(r^{-1})\,dz\,d\theta\,dr$$
$$\int_0^{\frac1M}O(z)\,dz+\int_M^{\infty}O(r^{-2})\,dr <\infty$$
The integral is finite. It converges absolutely - but you have to maintain the cancellation between the two terms. Keep that in mind when you try to evaluate it; splitting the integrand up is certain failure.

Comment: Computing the integral I obtained the expression up.How can I day it's integrable  ?

Comment: That it's integrable? It's potentially improper at zero and at $\infty$. Estimate it separately at each end.

Comment: Near zero the integrand function $g(z)\sim -1$   so there isn't problem